# How to add scroll to bottom automatically to Panel widget box

Tags: python, panel, holoviz-panel

```
output = pn.WidgetBox('*Conversations:*', qa_interactive, width=630, height=440, styles=custom_style1, scroll=True)
```

I have widget box for conversations like a chat bot and I'm calling the `openAI` and keeping the responses into widget box.

I could see the scroll bar but when the text exceeds the height of the widget box, I have scroll manually to see the conversations.

Is there a way to auto scroll to bottom?